# Using a JavaScript npm Package

Tags: javascript, node.js

***tl;dr***: I come from a Python background - where I would basically use `pip install foo`, then use the python interpreter to run code that uses `foo`. How does this translate to the world of JS?

---

I'm trying to use this package: https://github.com/skatejs/dom-diff

And execute this simple code example given by the author -

```
/** @jsx h **/
import { diff, h } from 'skatejs-dom-diff';

const source = <div><span>source</span></div>;
const target = <div><span>target</span></div>;
const instructions = diff(source, target);
```

Now I'm extremely new to the world of JS and just cannot figure out how I can run this code.

I was of course able to install this using `npm install skatejs-dom-diff`, but what now? I figured I might be able to run the code using `node`. So I saved the above code into `foo.js` and then executed `node foo.js`

```
% node foo.js                                             
/Users/foo/Dev/DomDiff/skatejs_dom-diff/foo.js:2
 import { diff, h } from 'skatejs-dom-diff';
 ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

When I tried to debug this, I kept going down the rabbit hole of Babel, JSX, ES6 etc etc, but to no real benefit since I'm even more confused still can't understand how to run this JS code.

Comment: If you are trying to use `npm` modules from the browser you could take a look to [Browserify](https://writingjavascript.org/posts/introduction-to-browserify#_=_). AFAIK, you can't install a `npm` package and use it directly in the browser.

Comment: Note. You don't need Browserify to use npm modules from the browser.

Comment: I don't need anything to do with the browser. I just need to run this JS code standalone. Is that not possible?

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to use here is a syntax for [EcmaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript), which is a super-set of JavaScript. In order to execute your ES code you need a transpiler like [Babel](https://babeljs.io) in order to convert your code from EcmaScript to Pure JavaScript, which can then be understood by node or your browser.

But, I recommend you to use pure JavaScript if you don't need to follow an Object-Oriented paradigm or the salient features of EcmaScript, that allow JavaScript to become a multi-paradigm language.

You can check out the major differences between the 2 [here](http://voidcanvas.com/import-vs-require/).

You can visit this [website](https://jasonformat.com/wtf-is-jsx/) to understand more about jsx and how to use it.

----Edit----

To fix your code you can follow these steps:

1. Open cmd and change directory to your project.
2. Type the command `npm i -g browserify`
3. Type the command `npm i -D babelify babelify-preset-2015`
4. Add the following code and save it as test.js

**test.js**

```
/** @jsx h **/
import { diff, h } from 'skatejs-dom-diff';

const source = h('div', h('span', 'source'));
const target = h('div', h( 'span' , 'target'));
const instructions = diff(source, target);
console.log(instructions);
```

5. Type the command `browserify test.js -o bundle.js -t [ babelify --presets [ es2015 ] ]`
6. Create a file index.html and add the following code to it.

**index.html**

```
<html>
<body>
<script src="bundle.js">
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

7. Open index.html in your browser and check the output in console (Right click->inspect->console)

Tada! :)

Comment: ECMAScript is not a super-set of JavaScript but the language specification that JavaScript (and others) implements.

Comment: I tried to run the fixed code using node and ran into another error. https://pastebin.com/BLgpUQHA. Again seems something isn't supported by vanilla JS

Comment: I am sorry I misunderstood. The library is built in ES6 you must have an ES6 transpiler to translate the code to run in node, also the library is a module to manipulate DOM elements in the browser thus it would require an html file into which the compiled source code is called using the script tag.